# Масштабируемая страница

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, viewport

Всем привет.
Подскажите,  как правильно реализовать.
Есть страница, нужно что бы при ширине менее 1024рх она масштабировалась.
Как пример этот [сайт](http://infomir.com.ua/)
Смотреть с мобильного,  или в режиме адаптивности.

Comment: используйте bootstrap

Comment: ознакомьтесь для начала хотя бы с фреймворком twitter boorstrap 4 - https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Я не использую готовые решения. У меня довольно таки большой опыт в веб разработке. 
Видимо я не правильно  задал вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением вопроса оказался метатег `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">`

Answer (score 1):

например @media. прописать стили для определенного размера экрана.

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { }

При размере экрана до 1024px будут использываны данные стили.
Свыше 1024px они будут игнорироваться.

Comment: Не много не то. Решением оказалось `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">`